Proposition 6.8 of Atiyah and Macdonald
Definition: A chain of submodule of a module $M$ is sequence $(M_i)_{i=0}^n$ of submodule of $M$ such that $$M=M_0\supset M_1\supset \cdots \supset M_n=0 \text{ (strict inclusions) }.$$
The length of the chain is $n$ (the number of “links”). A composition series of $M$ is a maximal chain, that is one in which no extra submodules can be inserted: that is equivalent to saying that each quotient $M_{i-1}/M_i$ $(1\leq i\leq n)$ is simple.


$M$ has a composition series$\iff$$M$ satisfies both chain conditions.
Proof. $\Rightarrow$: All chains in $M$ are of bounded length, hence both a.c.c. and d.c.c. hold.

In the proof, what is meant by “chain”? Is it sequence $(M_i)_{i=0}^n$ such that $M=M_0\supset M_1\supset \cdots \supset M_n=0$, or ascending/descending chain $M_1\supseteq M_2\supseteq \cdots$? In former case, length of chain is finite by definition, therefore bounded. In latter case, length is not defined on a.c./d.c. In my opinion, we have to first show a.c.c. and d.c.c. to say “All chain in $M$ are of bounded length”.

Earlier in the chapter it was proved that if there is a composition series of length $n$ then all chains (which are finite by definition, as you mentioned in the question) have length at most $n$. From here it clearly follows that there can't be an infinite ascending sequence which consists of strict inclusions. For if there was such a sequence:
$M_1\subseteq M_2\subseteq M_3\subseteq...$
then by taking the first $n+1$ modules we would get a chain $0\subseteq M_1\subseteq M_2\subseteq...\subseteq M_{n+1}\subseteq M$ of length longer than $n$, a contradiction.
Similarly, there can't be a non stabilizing descending sequence of modules.
